# Difference between SSL versions and TLS versions?

Tags: tls, certificates

Can anyone tell me the different versions of SSL and TLS? Someone says that SSL 1.0 was never released or never exist and other says that SSL 3.0 = TLS 1.0? Can anyone please clarify? Actually I am trying to enable TLS on my server(Apple APNS recommendation) but worried which version should I enable?